# Not able to find right library for MPU9250

Tags: sensors, library, mpu6050, imu

I am using an Arduino Uno and learning to use the motion sensor. Currently I was not able to find the library which looks simple and would like to get your suggestion. I found this https://github.com/hideakitai/MPU9250 library to be simple but don't know how to use it.

For example, take this code:-

```
#include "MPU9250.h"

MPU9250 mpu;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Wire.begin();

    delay(2000);
    mpu.setup();
}

void loop()
{
    static uint32_t prev_ms = millis();
    if ((millis() - prev_ms) > 16)
    {
        mpu.update();
        mpu.print();

        Serial.print("roll  (x-forward (north)) : ");
        Serial.println(mpu.getRoll());
        Serial.print("pitch (y-right (east))    : ");
        Serial.println(mpu.getPitch());
        Serial.print("yaw   (z-down (down))     : ");
        Serial.println(mpu.getYaw());

        prev_ms = millis();
    }
}
```

Some values are not defined here, like registration code and input pins. I am not used to reading the documentation code so might need help in that.

Comment: I didn't understand the docs

Comment: thanks for updating your post ..... you are asking the wrong question ..... you do not have a problem with the MPU9250 library ..... your problem is with I2C communication ..... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire

Comment: What is the problem here, are you getting any values? Yes, then good. Finding a simple solutions to complex problems isn't always a given. If it works, stick with it. If it doesn't work then show us the schematics? I would rely on this example since it's hiding all the logic. Until it's dis-proven.  You can build a schematic here to show us. (https://www.tinkercad.com/circuits). The code should work, but i dont see any code for wiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Arduino IDE, click on SKETCH > INCLUDE LIBRARY > MANAGE LIBRARIES.

[image]

Then, search for 9250, select the SparkFun one, and click INSTALL.

[image]

Finally, from the examples, choose the MPU9250BasicAHRS_I2C.